# DOM Not Loading In Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I have a simple HTML5 Snake game that uses canvas that I want to package as a Chrome App. Here is my normal HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Snake</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="snake.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="food.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="snake.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="point.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                    game = new Game(canvas, new Snake(canvas), new Food(canvas));
                game.init();
                game.run();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However the script in the HTML is not allowed. So I removed it and placed it main.js which creates the window. I provide a callback that is the same as `window.onload` above because my understanding is that this is the chrome app equivalent:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    "use strict";
    chrome.app.window.create('snake.html', {
        bounds: {
            width: 800,
            height: 800
        }
    }, function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            game = new Game(canvas, new Snake(canvas), new Food(canvas));
        game.init();
        game.run();
    });
});
```

This runs after the DOM appears to have loaded but `document.getElementById` always returns null. Looking at the document in the developer tools it looks like only the scripts are loaded even though I can see the canvas in the app window (I have a border around the canvas). Can anyone tell me what is going on? Where is the appropriate place to access the DOM from when `window.onload` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.js is running on the [background / event page](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle.html) and is not in the same context as the newly created window's DOM. You can interact with that context as documented on the [create callback](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#method-create), but it's not how I recommend solving this.

Instead, from your main.js simply create the window, and from the HTML file load script code that executes directly.

**window.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
        <script ...</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"></script>
```

**window.js:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
game = new Game(canvas, new Snake(canvas), new Food(canvas));
game.init();
game.run();
```